# How can I make this codepen work with multiple pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, transition

I am using this page transition effect that I found on codepen for all of my buttons. It works fine for my contact button, but when I try to create other pages it doesnt work. So if I try to create a page for my "about" button it will not work and it will just use the same page from my contact page. So basically my question is how can I use this codepen to create multiple buttons with different content on each button.

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/fralec/pen/xZBKzO

and here is the buttons from my site

```js
/* JS scripts are added see github repo for more 
https://github.com/fralec/ElegantJS */

$('#contact').elegant({
    clickNextToClose: true,
    newTab: true,
    github: {
        id: ''
    },
    twitter: {
        id: ''
    },
    mail: {
        id: ''
    },
    steam: {
        id: ''
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  color: #ccc;
  z-index: -100;
  background-color:black;
}

#home {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    height: 3em;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 4px;
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

#about {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-left: 37%;
    height: 3em;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 4px;
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

#projects {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-left: 54%;
    height: 3em;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 4px;
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

#contact {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-left: 71%;
    height: 3em;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 4px;
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

#home:hover {
    color: #1dd2e2;
    border: 3px solid #18bdef;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#about:hover {
    color: #1dd2e2;
    border: 3px solid #18bdef;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#projects:hover {
    color: #1dd2e2;
    border: 3px solid #18bdef;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#contact:hover {
    color: #1dd2e2;
    border: 3px solid #18bdef;
    font-weight: bold;
}

@keyframes grain {
  0%, 100% { transform:translate(0, 0) }
  10% { transform:translate(-5%, -10%) }
  20% { transform:translate(-15%, 5%) }
  30% { transform:translate(7%, -25%) }
  40% { transform:translate(-5%, 25%) }
  50% { transform:translate(-15%, 10%) }
  60% { transform:translate(15%, 0%) }
  70% { transform:translate(0%, 15%) }
  80% { transform:translate(3%, 35%) }
  90% { transform:translate(-10%, 10%) }
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Home</title>
    
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro|Play" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://rawgit.com/fralec/elegantShareJS/master/css/elegant.css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>  
<body>
    
    <button id="home">Home</button>
    <button id="about">About</button>
    <button id="projects">Projects</button>
    <button id="contact">Contact</button>
    
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/elegant.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/background.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look like all the "elegant" plugin does is generate social links https://github.com/fralec/ElegantJS/wiki are you wanting it to do more than that, or do you just want each button to show 4 unique sets of social links?

Comment: I want to be able to create a button that once clicked will do the same fade in animation and will show some content. For example an "about" button, where once you click it, it will open a page with a paragraph about me.

Comment: The example you showed just uses a social media link plugin - it doesn't transition normal pages, just a list of social media links.

Comment: Would it be possible to add text instead of the social media links?

Comment: Not with that plugin. I mean, it's possible... it would just be a pain in the ass and take forever. It would be easier to write that functionality from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the JS code from here: https://github.com/fralec/ElegantJS/blob/master/script/elegant.js
and use this new file as your script source for `elegant.js` instead of the rawgit url script source.

And then add your new buttons into the code following the same format like this:

`facebook: {
    id: null, 
    faIcon: "facebook",
    color: "#3b5998", 
    url: "https://www.facebook.com/",
    target: null},`

**facebook** - name of your new button

**id** - //If you need an id for this site put it here else keep null

**faIcon** - //put the Font Awesome icon you want for the button here

**color** - //This is the hover color

**url** - The url you want the button to take you to

Now in your js file, instead of this:

`facebook: {
        id: ''
    }`

do this

`newButtonName: {
  id: ''
},
 otherNewButtonName: {
  id: ''
}`

Now go and have fun hijacking someone else's code ;-)

Comment: Ok! I will try this.

Comment: it also has options for background color, button size, close button size, text color and fade effects.

Comment: Wait this is just creating buttons for the page that the js is creating right? I am trying to create a entire new page where I can write a paragraph or something. Because for some reason when I try to create a different page it doesnt work.

Comment: Example: https://pastebin.com/qnw16rXR , this code wouldnt work. It should make it so when I click the about button it brings up a blank page. But it doesnt, it brings up the same page as the contact button.

Comment: Yes, this is just for creating a modal containing buttons.

Comment: I would like to add text to a page instead of buttons

Comment: Is there a way to fade in something once a button is pressed, using only css? or a very simple way to do so in javascript?